# How to calculate the resolution of spectrometer at the emission edge of a metal in x-ray emission?

Tags: material-science, spectroscopy, x-rays, photon-emission

I wonder how I can calculate the resolution of the spectrometer from the Al L2,3 X-ray emission edge, and why this method is used to determine the resolution.
[image]

Comment: You haven't given us enough detail. It's quite specific to the spectrometer and application. For mine, I start with Mn K emission lines from Fe-55, and then use other lines within the spectrometer band to make a model of resolution versus energy based on full width at half maximum and/or Gaussian fits to line profiles.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDoty for your reply, for me, I do like what you said when the emission peak is symmetric, but in the case of Al or Mg L2,3 for example the emission peak is not really symmetrical (I added a screenshot of the emission in the question) with a sharp peak near the fermi edge.

Comment: Emission? Absorption? Your axes have no labels. What is the experimental setup?

Comment: It's x-ray emission, we just bombard sample with electrons and we collect and measure the generated x-rays using wavelength-dispersive spectrometer.

Comment: Excited by what? Measured by what?

Comment: How do you get L emission from Al?

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer to include more details!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144551/discussion-between-chameleon-and-john-doty).